# Using Javascript to extract error message from JSON returned by a Django REST API call

Tags: javascript, json, django, rest

I am using the Django rest-auth package with Django allauth to allow users to sign up with the /res-auth/registration api call.

If the registration fails I get some JSON returned to my Javascript web app that contains the reason for the failure. I am having difficulty working out how to extract the error reason for all cases. Here is an example of the JSON returned when the username is too short:

```js
{
   "_body":"{\"password1\":[\"This password is too short. It must contain at least 8 characters.\"]}",
   "status":400,
   "ok":false,
   "statusText":"Bad Request",
   "headers":{
      "Date":[
         "Sun",
         " 28 Aug 2016 16:56:40 GMT"
      ],
      "Content-Type":[
         "application/json"
      ],
      "Server":[
         "WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.4.3"
      ],
      "X-Frame-Options":[
         "SAMEORIGIN"
      ],
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":[
         "*"
      ],
      "Allow":[
         "POST",
         " OPTIONS"
      ]
   },
   "type":2,
   "url":"http://al8f24a9.ngrok.io/rest-auth/registration/"
}
```

How would I extract the failure reason if it was for password or if it was for username?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's too late but i had the same problem and i just solved it.
If you're working with `fetch`, before the first `then`, use another `then` like: `.then(response => response.json())`.